# Populate New Record Fields from Lookup Field

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, lookup

I have a custom object Booking__c which has a Related List of a custom object Notes__c. I want to reuse useful Notes for new Bookings as if any existing Note could be a template. On Notes__c I have fields Name, Visibility__c, Note__c(text area), Booking__c(lookup to Booking__c), Template(lookup to Notes__c). When Template__c is populated with an existing Note, I want to populate all the new Notes fields with the existing Note.

With the code below, i'm receiving an error:

> populateNotefromNoteTemplate: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.populateNotefromNoteTemplate: line 21, column 1

Here is my code:

```
trigger populateNotefromNoteTemplate on Note__c (before insert , before update) {
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert)
    {
        Set<ID> NoteIds = new Set<ID>();

        for(Note__c note : trigger.new)
        {
            NoteIds.add(note.Template__c);    
        }

        list <Note__c> notelist = [SELECT ID, Name, Visibility__c, Note__c FROM 
                                   Note__c WHERE ID IN:NoteIds];

        MAP<ID , Note__c> mapNote = new MAP<ID , Note__c>();
        for(Note__c n : Notelist)
        {
            mapNote.put(n.id, n);
        }

        for(Note__c note : trigger.new)
        {
            if(trigger.oldmap.get(note.Id).Template__c != note.Template__c){
                if(note.Template__c!=null)
                {
                    if(mapNote.containskey(note.Template__c))
                    {
                        Note__c n = mapnote.get(note.Template__c);
                        note.Name = n.Name;
                        note.Visibility__c = n.Visibility__c;
                        note.Note__c = n.Note__c;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    note.Name = null;
                    note.Visibility__c= null;
                    note.Note__c = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any particular reason why you would rather not use the process builder?

Comment: as per the error message,  populateNotefromNoteTemplate is null, hence your trigger is failing

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `trigger.old` nor `trigger.oldMap` in the `before insert` trigger context. They are both `null`. Note from **[Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)**:

> ```
> Variable    Usage
> old         Returns a list of the old versions of the sObject records.
>             This sObject list is only available in update and delete triggers.
>
> oldMap      A map of IDs to the old versions of the sObject records.
>             This map is only available in update and delete triggers.
> ```

If you want to filter for records which have a `Template__c` value which is new or changed, you would instead check:

```
if (trigger.oldMap != null || trigger.oldmap.get(note.Id).Template__c != note.Template__c)
```

---

You might also consider reading up on **[trigger best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)**, specifically:

- [One Trigger Per Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#One_Trigger_Per_Object)
  The way you have named your trigger implies you would write a separate file for each piece of trigger functionality. The industry standard is to incorporate all of your trigger logic into one trigger, so that you have fine-grained control over order of execution.
- [Logic-less Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#Logic-less_Triggers)
  One way to keep your trigger files from growing mighty unwieldy is to move the logic into an `Apex Class` (or several, more likely).

In light of these practices, I recommend you adopt a handler pattern and [service layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl) in the long run. You might also take a look at filtering libraries out there, of which [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) is a fine example.